# jQuery inline style rgb fallback for rgba color IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery to set the background of a div and i want to use rgba color in the browsers that support it but if they don't i would like to use rgb color as a fallback. I know how to achive this with plain css.

```
style="background: rgb(250, 0, 0); background: rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.5);"
```

Do you know how i could achieve this with jQuery `.css()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe if you use `css()`, it will overwrite the previous value for a property. If you want to do something like that, you can either set it manually via `attr()`, or you can use the callback function to see if it's IE or not, and set the value accordingly.

**using `attr()`**

```
$('element').attr('style','background: rgb(250, 0, 0); background: rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.5);');
```

**using `.css()`**

```
$('element').css('background', function() {
   // if you're using jquery version < 1.9
   if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 8) 
     return 'rgb(250, 0, 0);';
   else 
     return "rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.5)";
});
```

NOTE: if you're using jquery version 1.9 or above, `$.browser` is removed, so you will need to detect IE8 in a different way.

Answer (score -3):

You have to pass css two args

```
$(this).css("background-color", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
```

Comment: I must be misunderstanding the question.  This is how you would set an element's css with jquery...

Comment: If it's rgba you want, you can replace rgb with rgba.  a is a double value of course.

Comment: he's asking how would you set both, not one or the other.